# I dance with nobody & I dance without anybody

Tags: usage

I think *I dance with nobody* and *I dance without anybody* have the same meaning but are used slightly differently. Is it true?

Comment: Neither *I dance with nobody* nor *I dance without anybody* sound remotely idiomatic to me. Possible alternatives include ***I don't dance with anybody*** (which *might* imply that I *never* dance, no matter who asks me to dance with them) and ***I dance alone*** (which *always* implies that I do dance / am dancing, *without a dancing partner*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dance with nobody, the implication is that (a bit like Darcy at the ball) you see nobody who you regard as good enough for you.

I dance without anybody implies that you dance by yourself.

So, yes, they don't mean the same thing.

Comment: Could you give a reference for "Darcy at the ball" please. Learners of English are unlikely to be familiar with 19th century English literature. Thanks.

Comment: I know Darcy he in Pride and Prejudice

Comment: @하아아아앙  Indeed he is, a man who had to eat the biggest slice of humble pie in history in order to win over his girl, and didn't regret a crumb of it.